# Как сделать, чтобы программа компилировалась всеми популярными компиляторами?

Tags: c++, компиляция

Хочу устроить небольшой эксперимент, целью которого будет выяснение вопроса о необходимости избавляться от ветвлений в таких функциях как min, max, sign и abs. Каждый должен иметь возможность взять вот [этот cpp файл](https://github.com/Zealint/fastest_algorithm/blob/master/BranchFreeTimeout.cpp) (GitHub), скомпилировать, запустить и посмотреть на вывод в stdout. Программа выдает две колонки чисел: время работы функции с ветвлением и без него. Программа может работать долго, несколько минут (не пугайтесь, она не виснет).

Сейчас программа компилируется только в VС++ 2015 и в GCC 4.8.1 (из MinGW), а мне бы хотелось, чтобы она работала и в других компиляторах. Кто что может посоветовать сделать? От `std::chrono` мне не избавиться, время замерять нужно как-то более менее универсально, от `int32_t` тоже, так как я не знаю, вдруг у кого-то будет `int` размером 64 бита (мало ли). Возможно, я не во всём следую Стандарту или есть ещё какие-то ошибки?

**Важно вот что**: я отдаю себе отчёт, что код **зависит** от наличия знакового сдвига и дополнительного кода в представлении отрицательных чисел. **Так и было задумано**.

Comment: она нормально компилируется gcc 4.9.3 и clang 3.7 (с включенной опцией `-std=c++11`) в линуксе. И даже нет предупреждений от компилятора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведённый код компилируется «только в VС++ 2015 и в GCC 4.8.1», так как использует возможности стандарта C++11 (а именно `std::chrono` и заголовочный файл `cstdint`). Для того, чтобы программа собиралась на компиляторах, поддерживающих исключительно более ранние стандарты, необходимо:

1. Использовать функцию[`clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) из заголовочного файла `ctime`. Эта функция возвращает время в процессорных тактах, а потому идеально подходит для решения поставленной задачи.
2. Заменить включение `<cstdint>` на `<stdint.h>`. Оба заголовка имеют практически идентичное содержимое, однако последний был введён ещё в C99.

Comment: Туда же *auto*, которое до C++11 имело иной смысл